# Creating a Like Button for a Facebook Photo

Tags: facebook

Hey,
I'm trying to create Like Buttons for Facebook Photos, but can't figure out which URL to use. Or if it's even possible.
The problem is, that I want to display photos out of an Facebook Photo Album on a microsite and want to offer the visitors the possibility to like this photos, even when they're currently not visiting facebook.

The problem is: I want the likes (and if possible, comments, too!) on the microsite and facebook synchronized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested it and something like this will work:

```
$('#likebutton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes?method=POST&format=json&access_token=TOKEN,
       success: function(res) {
          // do something like style button
        }
    });
});
```

To unlike change the type to 'DELETE'

Remember that you will need to determine if you already like the object in question before making this call.

You could give like buttons a specific name and append the OBJECT_ID to the class in order to make each like button unique and have a method of getting the OBJECT_ID

You also need the permissions 'publish_actions' and 'publish_stream' for this to work.

Comment: You are right, it works. Crazy. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I'm actually working with graph api and I worked with what tiagoboldt said below.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing

Mentions it but doesn't go into much detail. I haven't tested if other users try to like the photo, I'm guessing they will have to allow the app permissions before it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a like button. You can only like the URL you're in with it, there's no way to synchronize both likes.

You would have to use the Graph API to get the photo ID and use it to like the photo itself: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: No, thats wrong. You can like whatever URL you want with a like button. I can put a like-button on my homepage and actually like a facebook page with it.

I already HAVE the Photo-ID, that's not the problem. I have the complete graph object of the photo which I want to get liked. But how can I tie it to a comments/like plugin?

Comment: That's what I was telling you. You can't do it automatically. You'll have to manually capture the click on the like button (that will like the URL) and issue a request for the graph api to like the same photo inside facebook itself. A better implementation would be to show the photos and likes using the graph api itself. You would always like though the graph api so it would be synced with facebook all the time.

Comment: erm... but you know that you can't like photos with graph/rest api?

Comment: sure you can.. read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ --> "You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments and https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes"

Comment: just to be clear, POST access_token=your_token to https://graph.facebook.com/pic_id/likes and you have liked the photo. If you GET the same url you get a list of the users who like the photo.

Comment: Don't want to wake a dead thread, but it just reappeares at my profile for being popular. Despite the comments above, there is NO way to like ANYTHING via REST/GRAPH. You just can't. Its only possible via Social Plugins. Period.